# L beam - Strange result

Tags: structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis

I have the following system (at P and Q there is a ball joint; the length of L beam is l; the PB and PA forces are applied at l/2 and are known; Fz is not zero and is known):

[image]

The system has 0 degrees of freedom because each ball joint removes three degrees of freedom (6-2*3=0). 
I replaced each ball joint with three unknown forces.

[image]

The problem is that the second cardinal equation along x gives:

$$-F_z \, l = 0$$

How can I solve the problem?

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: For planar force system you can write 3 equilibrium equations and only 3 reactions can be found this way. Your example is statically indeterminate. One of your bearings has to have only one reaction component, the other can have two for your problem to become determinate.

Comment: Hello @Katarina, my system is in the space and thus has 6 degrees of freedom. I wrote 6 equations, 3 for translation equilibrium and 3 for rotation equilibrium. The only equation which gives me problem is the rotational equation along x. Maybe do I miss somithing? Thank you.

Comment: I see, if this is 3D problem, you are missing PAz and PBz.

Comment: If A and B are e.g. bearings they limit translation in z direction thus there must be reactions PAz and PBz.

Comment: And you have - Fz x l+PAz x l/2 =0, or whichever direction of PAz you choose.

Comment: If points P and Q are ball joints and you have a nonzero force in the Z direction, what is preventing the model from rotating about the X axis through points P and Q?

Comment: @Katarina The PB and PA forces are forces of gravity (g vector has gx and gy components, not gz component).

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood conditions. How about choosing different origin for moment equation? I remember from mechanics classes that it can happen for moment to "hide" but only remeber that possible solution is to use different point for origin of moment equation. Maybe place of ball joint A? But it seems no matter which point you choose one moment equation would be usless.

Comment: Maybe choosing a point outside the beam, that is not located on the line of beam edge would be successful

Comment: John asked valid question about rotation. I didn't consider it. Some types of hinges in 3D space also have moment reaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system is still statically indeterminate, but not due to lack of DOF.  You have a singularity.  Having correct DOFs only assures you have a chance of being statically determinate, but it does not guarantee this condition.  In this case, the singularity is because the beam is allowed to rotate about the x axis unless $F_z$ is an unknown reaction.

As such, in this case, $F_zl = 0$ means $F_z = 0$.  Here are your other equations, in no particular order:

$$\begin{alignat}{4}
\sum& F_x &&= A + PB_x + D + PA_x &&= 0 \\
\sum& F_y &&= B + PB_y + E + PA_y &&= 0 \\
\sum& F_z &&= C + G + (F_z = 0) &&= 0 \\
\sum& M_{y@Q} &&= Cl &&= 0 \\
\sum& M_{x@Q} &&= F_zl &&= 0 \\
\sum& M_{z@Q} &&= -Bl + PB_yl/2 - PA_xl/2 &&= 0
\end{alignat}$$

We can immediately see $C = F_z = 0$. Because of $\sum F_z$, $G = 0$.  We now have four unknowns and three equations. We can solve for $B$ immediately using:

$$\sum M_{z@Q} = -Bl + PB_yl/2 - PA_xl/2 = 0$$

Rearranging, we can use this result for $B$ to solve for $E$ using:

$$\sum F_y = B + PB_y + E + PA_y = 0$$

But the final equation is singular:

$$\sum F_x = A + PB_x + D + PA_x = 0$$

This cannot be resolved using statics, but require static indeterminate methods.

Comment: Hello @Mark, your answer is excellent. Thank you so much.