# Independent constraints - Procedure to verify it

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, civil-engineering, structural-analysis, structures

I am wondering if there is a procedure to verify that the constraints of a system of rigid bodies are independent.

Here there is an example of a system with dependent constraints: [L beam - Strange result](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21869/l-beam-strange-result)

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: Apply this answer : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/21871/10902

Comment: Hello @SolarMike, the procedure in your link is good only in particular case. I need a general procedure.

Comment: Then re-work the equations...